# Constructor default parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, default-parameters

**Constructors:**

```
A()
{
    std::cout<<"In A const";
}

A(int a = 3)
{
    std::cout<<"In a with default :"<<a;
}
```

**Creating objects:**

```
A a;
A a1(4);
```

The above code is showing error: **call of overloaded 'A()' is ambiguous**

Comment: The compiler can not decide which constructor is called if no parameter is passed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've given a default value to the second constructor:

```
A(int a = 3)
```

So this covers both instances of:
`A()` and `A(3)`, making the first definition redundant